# Postgres trigger function: substitute value before insert or update

Tags: postgresql, function, syntax, triggers, plpgsql

I've looked up pretty much everything I could find regarding this issue, but I still don't understand what is wrong with this trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_SubstitutePostLatLng_Upt()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF OLD.post_latlng IS NULL AND NEW.post_latlng IS NULL AND NEW.place_guid IS NOT NULL THEN
    raise notice 'SELECT';
    SELECT place.geom_center, place.city_guid 
            INTO NEW.post_latlng, NEW.city_guid 
    FROM public.place 
    WHERE (place.origin_id, place.place_guid) IN (VALUES (NEW.origin_id,NEW.place_guid));
    raise notice 'Value db_geom: %', NEW.post_latlng;
    raise notice 'Value db_city_guid: %', NEW.city_guid;
    IF NEW.post_latlng IS NOT NULL THEN
            NEW.post_geoaccuracy = 'place';
            IF NEW.city_guid IS NOT NULL THEN
                SELECT country_guid INTO NEW.country_guid
                FROM public.city WHERE (origin_id, city_guid) IN (VALUES (NEW.origin_id,NEW.city_guid));
            END IF;            
    END IF;
    END IF;   
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trig_SubstitutePostLatLng_Upd on public.post;
CREATE TRIGGER trig_SubstitutePostLatLng_Upd
BEFORE UPDATE
ON public.post
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() < 1)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_SubstitutePostLatLng_Upt()
```

(I have a second similar trigger for insert)

The code is supposed to do the following:
On Update on table "post", check if no post_latlng is submitted (=NULL), and if yes, substitute post_latlng from table place (geom_center), if available.

However, no matter what I do, I get the following when updating an entry in table "post" (=triggering the above trigger):

```
NOTICE:  SELECT 
NOTICE:  Value db_geom: <NULL> 
NOTICE:  Value db_city_guid: <NULL> 
INSERT 0 1

Query returned successfully in 47 msec.
```

The test-data for place_guid, geom_center etc. is definitely available and both 
       `raise notice 'Value db_geom: %', NEW.post_latlng;` 
       `raise notice 'Value db_city_guid: %', NEW.city_guid;`
should not output NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several smaller issues, it now works. Here is a more cleaner code that uses variables in between:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_SubstitutePostLatLng_Upt()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    db_geom_center text;
    db_city_guid text;
    db_country_guid text;
BEGIN
    IF OLD.post_latlng IS NULL AND NEW.post_latlng IS NULL AND NEW.place_guid IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT place.geom_center, place.city_guid 
                INTO db_geom_center, db_city_guid
        FROM public.place 
        WHERE (place.origin_id, place.place_guid) IN (VALUES (NEW.origin_id,NEW.place_guid));
        IF db_geom_center IS NOT NULL THEN
                NEW.post_latlng = db_geom_center;
                NEW.post_geoaccuracy = 'place';
        END IF;
        IF db_city_guid IS NOT NULL THEN
            NEW.city_guid = db_city_guid;
            SELECT city.country_guid 
                INTO db_country_guid
            FROM public.city
            WHERE (city.origin_id, city.city_guid) IN (VALUES (NEW.origin_id,db_city_guid));
            NEW.country_guid = db_country_guid;
        END IF;            
    END IF;   
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```